# Why is splicing an array in JavaScript removing the last few elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm currently working on an array function that converts subarrays of consecutive numbers into strings denoting that range of numbers — for example, this array...

`[1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 10, 11, 12, 15, 18]`

...would become *this* array:

`["1-3", 6, 8, "10-12", 15, 18]`

I've been able to develop a function that *mostly* works, but I've encountered a weird error where all the elements past the final range of numbers spliced into the array are completely deleted. For example, the test array above actually becomes this:

`["1-3", 6, 8, "10-12"]`

This is the code I've written so far. It's not super pretty yet, but as I mentioned above, it gets the job done right up until the very end:

```js
let testArray = [1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 10, 11, 12, 15, 18];

for (i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++) {
  let consecutives = [];
  consecutives.push(testArray[i]);
  let j = i + 1;
  while (j < testArray.length) {
    if (testArray[j] == (testArray[j - 1] + 1)) {
      consecutives.push(testArray[j]);
      j++;
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
  if (consecutives.length > 2) {
    let range = String(testArray[i]) + "-" + String(testArray[j - 1]);
    console.log(testArray);
    console.log(testArray[i]);
    console.log(testArray[j]);
    testArray.splice(i, j, range);
  }
}

console.log(testArray);
```

These are the console logs output by that code:

```
Array(10) [ 1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 10, 11, 12, 15, 18 ]
1
6
Array(8) [ "1-3", 6, 8, 10, 11, 12, 15, 18 ]
10
15
Array(4) [ "1-3", 6, 8, "10-12" ]
```

I initially figured this was caused by a mix-up with array indexes, but playing around with the `index-1`s hasn't fixed the problem yet. Has anyone else ever had a similar issue with JavaScript's splicing, and if so, how were you able to get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do:

```
testArray.splice(i, j, range);
```

You are forgetting that `j` is the right limit index of the array that you want to erase, so you need to subtract `i` that is the left limit:

```
testArray.splice(i, j - i, range);
```

```js
let testArray = [1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 10, 11, 12, 15, 18];

for (i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++) {
  let consecutives = [];
  consecutives.push(testArray[i]);
  let j = i + 1;
  while (j < testArray.length) {
    if (testArray[j] == (testArray[j - 1] + 1)) {
      consecutives.push(testArray[j]);
      j++;
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
  if (consecutives.length > 2) {  // doesn´t it should be > 1 ??
    let range = String(testArray[i]) + "-" + String(testArray[j - 1]);
    console.log(testArray);
    console.log(testArray[i]);
    console.log(testArray[j]);
    testArray.splice(i, j - i, range);
  }
}

console.log(testArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in one line of code:

```
        testArray.splice(i, j, range);
```

According to the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), the second argument specifies how many elements in the array to delete.

> `deleteCount`
>
> An integer indicating the number of elements in the array to remove from start.

However, the code defines this argument as the index of the last array to remove from:

```
    let j = i + 1;
```

The solution is to get the difference between `i` and `j` before passing it to `splice`:

```
        testArray.splice(i, j - i, range);
```